# TFS Project Deleted, how to upload code to new project

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Somehow on my team's TFS server, one of our projects got deleted.  The code is on my local machine though so I'm trying to get it reuploaded, but I'm running into issues getting it back on the server.  I've recreated the project and given it the same name and Visual Studio seems to recognize that the new project I've created is connected to the Project I'm trying to upload as a result.  The problem is that when I try to check in the version I have to the new project it throws a pile of errors because the files "does not exist at the specified version or you do not have permission to access it".  Is there some way to force the upload so that the files are all on the server again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First remove .* folder from your current working project.
2. Then go to Visual Studio
3. Open Team Explorer
4. Click On Manage Connection
5. Add your account If not added
6. Enter your tfs url
7. Select your TFS folder where you want to checked in your code.
8. Try to checked in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have deleted the project on server side, all changes in TFS are non-destructive.

[image]

You could check this, just navigate to the **Source Control –> Visual Studio Team Foundation Server section.**

In that section is a check box that says "**Show deleted items in the Source Control Explorer**"

[image]

If you have recreated the project and given it the same name and want check in local code to TFS. This may cause some trouble.

Suggest you to permanently destroy  the project in TFS  using  [Destroy Command (Team Foundation Version Control)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/destroy-command-team-foundation-version-control)

```
tf destroy [/keephistory] <itemspec1>[;<versionspec>][<itemspec2>...<itemspecN>] 
[/stopat:<versionspec>] [/preview] [/startcleanup] [/noprompt] [/silent] [/login:username,[password]] [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl]]
```

After destroy the old project, then create a new project with the same name, add your local code to this project, finally check in pending changes.